# What is a cross browser solution for printing the contents of an element on a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am currently trying to print the contents of an element on a page, and I have found the following resources,

```
http://www.808.dk/?code-javascript-print
http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/108117
http://vikku.info/codesnippets/javascript/print-div-content-print-only-the-content-of-an-html-element-and-not-the-whole-document/
```

They are all doing some sort of variation of what I already have which is like the following,

```
function printelement() {
    var parentdiv = $(this).parent().parent();
    var iframeEle = $(document.createElement("iframe")).attr("id", "print" + formParams.fpid).css({ width: "2250px", display: "none" }).appendTo("body");
    var doc = document.getElementById("print" + formParams.fpid).contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();

    //get stylesheets
    $("link[type='text/css']").each( function() {
        doc.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "' />");
    });

    //writes all the contents of div to new iframe
    $(parentdiv).each( function() {
        doc.write($(this).html());
    });

    //print the iframe
    var giframe = parentdiv.contents().find("iframe");
    var printdiv2 = giframe.prevObject[0].id;

    if(printdiv2) {
        if($.browser.msie) {
            var iedoc = giframe.prevObject[0].contentWindow.document;
            iedoc.execCommand('print', false, null);
        } 
        else { giframe.prevObject[0].contentWindow.print(); }
    } 
    else {
         if($.browser.msie){
            doc.execCommand('print', false, null);
         } 
         else { iframeEle[0].contentWindow.print(); }
    }
}
```

This seems to work just fine in FF, and Chrome (although Chrome keeps telling me I cant print within a certain amount of time). However, in IE it is just giving me blank results. How can I get this code to be cross browser, or do it differently?

Comment: are you using html5 elements? ie chokes on printing them, but there is a shiv...

Comment: Why aren't you just using a print media style sheet? No script required.

Comment: I did not write this code, but I also do not have time to change it to this functionality right now.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than messing with iframes (feels rather hacky to me), I'd do the following:

- Wrap all of the content within your `<body>` in `<div id="mainContent">...</div>`
- When the user chooses to print, place that special element in a separate div, hide `#mainContent`, and print the entire page
- (Be sure that you have all CSS set the hide backgrounds etc when printing)
- Include a link to return to "normal" view, which restores the page
- (You'll likely want to hide the 'close print view' link via print-specific CSS too)

...

```
if ($('#mainContent').length == 0)
   $('body').children().wrapAll('<div id="mainContent" />');
var toPrint = $('#whateverToPrint');
var origParents = [toPrint.prev(), toPrint.parent()];
toPrint.appendTo('body').wrap('<div id="printWrapper"></div>');
$('<a href="#">Close Print View</a>').appendTo('#printWrapper').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    // Move the element back into place
    if (origParents[0].length > 0)
        toPrint.insertAfter(origParents[0])
    else
        toPrint.prependTo(origParents[1]);

    // Remove wrapper and restore original content
    $('#printWrapper').remove();
    $('#mainContent').show();
});
$('#mainContent').hide();
setTimeout(function()
{
    window.print();
}, 100); // wait for DOM to catch up
```

Sound good, or am I reinventing the wheel?

Comment: The problem with taking an element out of the DOM and inserting it into a new document is that it may destroy the layout of that section of the document, even if you include the the style sheets from the original.

Comment: @RobG Not sure what you mean by 'new document,' but still a good caveat.  But you'll still have that problem if you move the content to an `iframe`.

Comment: I do agree that its a bit hackish, but I also feel that this is just as hackish. At this point, I was really hoping there was a simple straight forward way to do this in javascript, without having to jack with the display or anything like that. I basically have one day left to do this, otherwise the print will be left broken until the next set of updates goes out.